# How to get reverse geocode from php curl json

Tags: php, json, curl

i want to echo only fromatted_address from json but dont know how?
code below:

```
    <?PHP
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.569794,88.357934';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, False);   //only header 
print "<pre>";
$bko = print_r(curl_exec($ch));
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: just use `json_decode($string, true)` to convert it to an array

Comment: hi i want to echo "formatted_address" from json array, I already print it i only want to echo formatted_address- pls got stuck on it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the returned json string into `json_decode` to convert it to an array, then access the keys of the array as you normally would do.

```
$array = json_decode($json_result, true);

foreach($array['results'] as $k => $result) {
 echo $result['formatted_address'] . PHP_EOL;   
}
```

**returns**

> 50, Chittaranjan Ave, Bowbazar, Kolkata, West Bengal 700012, India
>
> CR Ave Rd, Bowbazar, Kolkata, West Bengal 700012, India
>
> Bowbazar, Kolkata, West Bengal, India
>
> Calcutta, West Bengal 700001, India
>
> Calcutta, West Bengal 700012, India
>
> Calcutta, West Bengal, India
>
> West Bengal, India
>
> India

[example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6bbbad40ef34b20fed0beef1b1f94fe1910092c)

Comment: thnx DONE with it.